# dismiss vs present with xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift3

As I'm learning Swift 3 and Xcode 8, I've come to a point where Im now confused or to know when to use the correct switching methods. To cancel you dismiss, back you go back but back button can be a dismiss?

Which is best practice in terms of memory usage?

```
@IBAction func backArrowTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let dc: DashboardVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dashboardVC") as! DashboardVC
        self.present(dc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

//or

 @IBAction func backArrowTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

How would you structure your `back` or `cancel` button action? When to use either functions above?

Comment: If you move forward make sure you return back to home at night..... :) If present, dismiss.If push, pop.if add view ,remove view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you overthink about it... using *present* and *dismiss* methods is a pretty simple.

Let's mention a trivial example to make it more clear:

Consider that you have tow ViewControllers, The first one called `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` for the second one.

[**present(_:animated:completion:):**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present)

> Presents a view controller modally.

By default the initial view controller is `FirstViewController` (the first view controller appears to the user), it has a button that when the users taps it, it should presents the second one; Its action should be implemented as the first `@IBAction` in your code snippet! That causes to present `SecondViewController` on top of `FirstViewController`.

[**dismiss(animated:completion:):**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss)

> Dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the view
>   controller.

For `SecondViewController`, let's say that it should has a 'cancel' button, when the user taps it, it should dismiss the current appeared view controller (which is `SecondViewController`), the dismiss button's action should be implemented as the second `@IBAction` in your code snippet.

*Recap:*

*present* method should be called in the first view controller to shows the second view controller; *dismiss* should be called in the second view controller do 'cancel' it and back to the first view controller.

---

**ALSO:**

Note that *present/dismiss* are NOT the same as *push/pop*. For more information, check [UINavigationController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller).

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

To move from one VC to other, you have following methods:

1. Present VC
2. Create Child VC
3. Push to VC

Now in the first two methods, the `UINavigationController` contains the parent VC in stack not the other VC you are adding into your controller. But in the third case whenever you push the VC then new VC is added into the stack.

Now you are confusing between when to use `Cancel` and when to use `Back`, so make it clear, whenever you are removing VC from `UINavigationController` then use `Back` option because you are navigating from one VC to other. And whenever you are in a single parent controller vc (i.e. case 1 and case 2) use `Cancel` option because you are removing its subview from the parent.

Hope now you have been cleared and if still have issue then ask.

Comment: Thats my question. Could you show me a typical `back` and `cancel` function?

Comment: @Sylar Yeah back can be dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

When you push a view controller then the preferred convention is to use back button.
On the other hand when you present view controller modally then you should use cancel button to dismiss the presented view controller.

In the case you have mentioned, you are presenting the second view controller modally, so the preferred way is to use Cancel Button.